# Use awk in Spyder's IPython Console

Tags: python, awk, spyder

I want to remove extra headings from my file and am using the following:

```
awk '{ print $1}' test.txt > output.txt
```

And then I get the next few lines back in response:

```
    File "<ipython-input-23-aa9db656210f>", line 1
    awk '{ print $1}' test.txt > output.txt
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not really sure where I am going wrong, is there something I am missing about the awk command? Do I need to install some extra package? I am using Spyder IDE...

Comment: Awk is a bash command, not a python command.  Bash and python are different languages so you cant use bash commands when coding in python.

Comment: @gbtimmon It's not part of Bash, though. It's a separate executable that you can call from any shell.

Comment: You can run bash commands in IPython by prefixing them with `!`. In this case this corresponds to `!awk '{ print $1}' test.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Even if you do not use IPython there are ways to access your external shell in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @BenjaminW. good clarification -- I was trying to keep my response on a level that someone making this mistake would understand so I intentionally left that complication out.

Comment: Are you trying to remove a single header row from a file? If so you can use `!awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' test.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

From [Carlos Cordoba's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089235/python-awk-syntax#comment89170977_51089235):

> You can run bash commands in IPython by prefixing them with `!`. In this case this corresponds to `!awk '{ print $1}' test.txt > output.txt`